# Can you change the path pyinstaller thinks python.exe is in?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, pip, pyinstaller

I want to use pyinstaller to make standalone exe files. I used

```
pip install pyinstaller
```

first, then I got an error message I will show you in a second, so I used

```
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
```

because I found it on a `pyinstaller` website. So I `cd` into the folder my script is in, and I think you don't need a `setup.py` file or anything for `pyinstaller` like you would need using `py2exe`, then I use the command

```
pyinstaller file.py --onefile
```

and I get the error message (I am translating the last part so it is not 100% accurate)

> Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"c:\python\python.exe"  "C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe" gtaReminder.py --onefile': System could not find the specified file.

I think `pyinstaller` thinks that `python.exe` is located in `c:\python\python.exe` as it says in the error message. I just opened the path and it is not. Can I somehow change this path pyinstaller thinks it can find `python.exe` in? I am using `python 3.6.2`, `pip 20.3.3` on windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, your command line syntax is wrong, it is always supposed to be optional arguments followed by the mandatory arguments, below is the general syntax

> pyinstaller [options] script [script …] | specfile

Read the documentation [here](https://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/usage.html).

The correct command should be

```
pyinstaller --onefile file.py
```

The error does not suggest that `pyinstaller` has got the wrong python file, the fact that it could tell

> Unable to create process using '"c:\python\python.exe" "C:\Python\Scripts\pyinstaller.exe"

means that it was able to find the python file and tried initiating the process but failed to perform the task altogether.